# Swift UITableView delegate and dataSource declaration and retain cycles

Tags: ios, swift

As far as I understood, to use the delegate pattern in swift I had to declare a property like so:

```
weak var delegate: TheDelegateProtocol!
```

And a protocol like so:

```
@class_protocol protocol TheDelegateProtocol {

}
```

To avoid retain cycle and stick with what we are used to do in objective C.

Now, if I look at what they have in the UITableView definition, I only see:

```
var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource!
var delegate: UITableViewDelegate!
```

And:

```
protocol UITableViewDelegate : NSObjectProtocol, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    [...]
}
```

I guess that's related to the fact that it is actually only bindings to Objective C, and the objective C definition might take precedence over the swift definition, but I can't find an official explanation in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This is for the same reason that in general many Cocoa delegates are not weak. Large parts of Cocoa are not written using ARC - because they precede it. They are managing memory manually, as we used to have to do in the good old days. So they don't get the delights of ARC-weak (which is what `weak` indicates here). They use pure, non-memory-managed assignment of delegates (and data sources). They don't retain it, so there's no retain cycle; but since they are not using ARC, they are not crash-safe.

Thus it remains *your* responsibility not to let such a delegate go out of existence during the lifetime of the primary instance, lest it attempt to send a message to a dangling pointer and crash.

You can see this by experimentation (this is Objective-C but you'll readily see the point):

```
self->_obj = [NSObject new];
nav.delegate = self->_obj // nav is our navigation controller, the root view controller
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // cry havoc, and let slip the dogs of war!
    self->_obj = nil; // releases obj - now what is nav.delegate pointing to??
    NSLog(@"Nav Controller delegate: %@", ((UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController).delegate); // if you're lucky it might print something!
    // or more likely it will just crash, or maybe print and *then* crash
});
```

That kind of crash is exactly what ARC-weak prevents, because it replaces the dangling pointer by nil automatically - and a message to nil, in Objective-C, is harmless.

Comment: And see my discussion at the end of this section: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_retain_cycles_and_weak_references

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer, I understand your answer very well, as I started using ObjC pre-ARC and got caught by this type of crash. But my question was more about how do they write this swift code that is clearly just mirroring objective-C header file in swift.

Comment: Just to be clearer, I know they didn't have "weak" at that time, but still, they had "assign". Which does not reflect in the swift representation.

Comment: Because Swift has no `assign`!

Comment: Yes, that's why there is weak. The thing is that I can't see it in the UITableView file provided by the framework. Anyway there is something strange about this, my app crashes when using weak..

Comment: That would be a different question.