# Why isn't the attribute of UITableView's delegate property weak

Tags: ios, objective-c

I found this in UITableView's header file and almost every property is non-arc style though my project is using ARC.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id <UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id <UITableViewDelegate>   delegate;
```

Why Apple don't use `weak` property instead of `assign`, is it a backward compatibility for non-arc ? If so, why not use `__has_feature(objc_arc)` to distinguish ARC and non-ARC.

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
@property (nonatomic, weak)   id <UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, weak)   id <UITableViewDelegate>   delegate;
#else
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id <UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id <UITableViewDelegate>   delegate;
#endif
```

I hope `delegate` is weak so I don't need to set the delegate to nil when the delegate instance is deallocated.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**

I note that `__has_feature(objc_arc)` is wrong because I can use ARC when my deployment target is 4.3, but then I can't use `weak`. So the condition should be whether my deployment target is equal to 5.0 or above.

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_5_0
@property (nonatomic, weak)   id <UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, weak)   id <UITableViewDelegate>   delegate;
#else
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id <UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id <UITableViewDelegate>   delegate;
#endif
```

Comment: See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24469143/341994 It is not "backwards compatible to non-ARC"; it _is_ non-ARC.

Comment: @matt Thank you very much. Do you think it is better if Apple using `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_5_0` to provide a better Cocoa with ARC supported ? Or it is very hard to achieve that.

Comment: These parts of Cocoa are old. They are not going to change any time soon. They precede ARC by many years. They are what they are. Move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why Apple don't use `weak property` instead of assign, is it a backward compatibility for non-arc ?

I have done some [research and found](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/#Reference_Counting) that, the __weak is synonymous to the “assign” modifier. But only difference is in assign the delegate instance will not set as nil when it is deallocated. You normally use assign modifier for IBOutlets and delegates. Under ARC, this is replaced with __weak. However, there is a caveat. __weak requires you to deploy the app on a runtime that supports zero-ing weak references. This includes, >=(iOS 5 and Lion). Snow Leopard or iOS 4 and older operating systems don’t support zero-ing weak references. This obviously means you cannot use __weak ownership modifiers if you plan to deploy to older operating systems. So Yes, in this sensitive it is a backward compatibility for non-arc.

Comment: You say __weak is synonymous to assign modifier, but when I use assign, after the delegate instance is deallocated, the delegate won't be set to nil as __weak modifier does.

Comment: Yes sir it is true. Have updated, did you follow the link and description. You will sort it out the reason.

Comment: Thanks, I will see the link later :)

Comment: Although you didn't answer the question "Why doesn't apple use #if #else to use support weak to all app that are deployment to 5.0 and above", I will accept it because I think maybe only apple know the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you have a delegate that's assign, it makes it very important to always set that delegate value to nil whenever the object is going to be deallocated - so an object should always be careful to nil out delegate references in dealloc if it has not done so elsewhere.

Thus assigning delegate, any reference left set, will be invalid after an object is deallocated (pointing at memory no longer allocated to the kind of object expected) - and thus cause a crash if you try to use it. A sign of this in the debugger is when the debugger claims some variable has a type that seems totally wrong from what the variable is actually declared as.

This might be the very reason **“Why isn't the attribute of UITableView's delegate property weak
“**

Hope this might help you.